# What is the formula for this numerical series?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion, number-theory

I'm developing a questions game. My goal is that the score for each correct answer will increase as the user answers more questions. Initially there are 15 points for each correct answer. Every 4 questions adds 2 points to the previous value. In terms of numerical series would be something like:

```
15 15 15 15 17 17 17 17 19 19 19 19 21 21 21 21.
```

I trying to find the formula for this numerical serie but I have not had success. If anyone sees in this numerical series a "challenge" and wants to help me find the formula I will be very grateful.

Comment: Check `FindGeneratingFunction`. It is generating equation.

Comment: Related: http://oeis.org/A129756

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly:

```
f[n_] := 13 + Ceiling[n, 4]/2;

f[Range[20]]
```

> ```
> {15, 15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 21, 21, 21, 21, 23, 23, 23, 23}
> ```

More general approach:

```
sample = {15, 15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 21, 21, 21, 21};
linrec = FindLinearRecurrence[sample]
```

> ```
>  {1, 0, 0, 1, -1}
> ```

```
f2[n_] := LinearRecurrence[linrec, sample[[1 ;; Length[linrec]]], n];
f2[20]
```

> ```
> {15, 15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 21, 21, 21, 21, 23, 23, 23, 23}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Use `FindGeneratingFunction` and `SeriesCoefficient`:

```
FindGeneratingFunction[
  {15, 15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 21, 21, 21, 21, 23, 23, 23, 23}, x]
```

> ```
> (15 - 13*x^4)/((-1 + x)^2*(1 + x + x^2 + x^3))
> ```

The formula:

```
FullSimplify[SeriesCoefficient[%, {x, 0, n}], Element[n, Integers] && n >= 0]
```

> ```
> (1/4)*(57 + (-1)^n + 2*n + 2*Cos[(n*Pi)/2] + 2*Sin[(n*Pi)/2])
> ```

Verification:

```
Table[%, {n, 0, 30}]
```

> ```
> {15, 15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
>  23, 23, 23, 23, 25, 25, 25, 25, 27, 27, 27, 27, 29, 29, 29}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

A nice use for the outer product:

```
Flatten@Outer[Times, Range[15, 23, 2], {1, 1, 1, 1}]

{15, 15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 21, 21, 21, 21, 23, 23, 23, 23}
```